# How to call javascript function in cakePHP controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.3

How to call javascript function in controller as below

In example.js

```
function hello(){
  alert("hi");
}
```

In exampleController.php

```
function index(){
   hello();
}
```

Comment: You can't call JavaScript function from the controller, controller is running on server-side, and your java script code running under the browser/client side, If you want to call javaScript function you must have to render view and call from that. you also try `$this->Html->scriptBlock('alert("hi")');` code to call javaScript function from the view.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call JavaScript function from the controller,

controller is running on server-side, and your java script code running under the browser/client side.

If you want to call javaScript function you must have to render view and call from that.

You can also try 
`$this->Html->scriptBlock('alert("hi")');` 
code to call javaScript function from the view.